# How can I add a model in custom CBV view?

Tags: python, django, backend

My custom CBV is working fine but When I open a page it displays nothing.
All I want is when a get() is called it displays a Blog Post and form underneath the post and when form is filled it calls the post() and save it in the database. but when I open a blog post it displays nothing.
before moving to Custom CBV I was using the (detailView) everything was fine.

```
class DetailView(View):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "blogs/details.html"
    model = BLOG

    def get(self, request, slug):
        forms = self.form_class(None)
        blogs = self.model
        context = {'forms': forms, "blogs":blogs}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        forms = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if forms.is_valid():
            user_comment = forms.save(commit=False)
            Name = cleaned_data["Name"]
            Email = cleaned_data["Name"]
            comment = cleaned_data['comment']
            user_comment.save()
```

blogs/details.html

```
{% extends "blogs/main.html" %}
{% block dyn_title %}{{blog.blog_title}}{% endblock dyn_title %}
{% block body %}

   <h2>{{blog.blog_title}}</h3>

   <p> {{blog.blog_body|safe}} </p>

   <form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% include "blogs/form_template.html" %}
   </form>

 {% endblock body %}

 <!-- form_template.html -->
  {% for field in form %}
    <label>{{field.label_tag}}</label>
    <div class="">
      {{field}}
     </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `blogs = self.model.objects.filter(slug=slug)`.

Comment: Blogs = self.model.objects.get (slug=slug) worked but form is still not showing up

Comment: Show us the `blogs/details.html` template.

Comment: It's underdevelopment. I have updated it in the question.

Comment: `{% for field in forms %}`.

Comment: Oh so It was a typo. Thanks alot I was banging my head on this since thursday.